# Converting an ImageMagick FX operator to pure Python code with PIL

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to port some image processing functionality from an Image Magick
command (using the [Fx Special Effects Image Operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php)) to Python using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  My
issue is that I'm not entirely understanding what this fx operator is doing:

```
convert input.png gradient.png -fx "v.p{0,u*v.h}" output.png
```

From a high level, this command takes the colors from a gradient image
([gradient.png](http://markovchainsaw.com/misc/magick/gradient.png)) and applies them as the color palette of the input image
([input.png](http://markovchainsaw.com/misc/magick/input.png)), writing to an output image ([output.png](http://markovchainsaw.com/misc/magick/output.png)).

From what I've figured out, **u** is the input image, **v** is the gradient, and it is
going through each left-most pixel in the gradient from top to bottom,
**somehow** applying its colors to the input image.

I can't wrap my head around how to do this same thing programmatically with
PIL.  The best thing I've come up with was to convert the image to a paletted
image (down-sampling to a measly 256 colors) and grabbing colors individually
from the gradient with a pixel access object.

```
import Image

# open the input image
input_img = Image.open('input.png')

# open gradient image and resize to 256px height
gradient_img = Image.open('gradient.png')
gradient_img = gradient_img.resize( (gradient_img.size[0], 256,) )

# get pixel access object (significantly quicker than getpixel method)
gradient_pix = gradient_img.load()

# build a sequence of 256 palette values (going from bottom to top)
sequence = []
for i in range(255, 0, -1):
    # from rgb tuples for each pixel row
    sequence.extend(gradient_pix[0, i])

# convert to "P" mode in order to use putpalette() with built sequence
output_img = input_img.convert("P")
output_img.putpalette(sequence)

# save output file
output_img = output_img.convert("RGBA")
output_img.save('output.png')
```

This works, but like I said, it down-samples to 256 colors.  Not only is
this a ham-handed way of doing things, it results in a really crappy output
image.  How could I duplicate the Magick functionality without cramming the
result into 265 colors?

**addendum:** forgot to cite the [blog where I found the original Magick command](http://blog.corunet.com/english/how-to-make-heat-maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been about a month and you might has already figured it out. But here is the answer.

From ImageMagicK documentation I was able to understand what the effect is actually doing.

```
convert input.png gradient.png -fx "v.p{0,u*v.h}" output.png

v is the second image (gradient.png)
u is the first image (input.png)
v.p will get a pixel value
v.p{0, 0} -> first pixel in the image
v.h -> the hight of the second image
v.p{0, u * v.h} -> will read the Nth pixel where N = u * v.h
```

I converted that into PIL, and the result looks exactly like you want it to be:

```
import Image

# open the input image
input_img = Image.open('input.png')

# open gradient image and resize to 256px height
gradient_img = Image.open('gradient.png')
gradient_img = gradient_img.resize( (gradient_img.size[0], 256,) )

# get pixel access object (significantly quicker than getpixel method)
gradient_pix = gradient_img.load()

data = input_img.getdata()
input_img.putdata([gradient_pix[0, r] for (r, g, b, a) in data])
input_img.save('output.png')
```

Comment: thanks, that works beatifully!  i'd figured out a similar algorithm (with much banging of head and keyboard, and lots of help from the imagemagick folk), but I think yours might actually be more efficient than mine anyway